# Problema en comparación mayor o igual en Java

Tags: java

Este es el código

```
 if( contrasenaI => 17 ){
 System.out.println(" enhorabuena, ha conseguido entrar a MexCex.");
} else {
 System.out.println(" [Error] nombre de usuario o contraseña incorrectos");
}
```

Este es el error

> MexCex.java:23: error: illegal start of expression
>        if( contrasenaI => 17 ){
>                         ^ 1 error

Comment: Es un error tipográfico, `=>` debería escribirse `>=`, motivo por le cual voto para cerrar esta pregunta

Answer (score 5):

Es porque tu operador en la clausura `if` se encuentra al revés, debería ser

```java
if(valor1 >= valor2){}
```

Tu código quedaría de la siguiente manera

```java
if( contrasenaI >= 17 ){ //primero el signo > y luego el =
   System.out.println(" enhorabuena, ha conseguido entrar a MexCex.");
} else {
   System.out.println(" [Error] nombre de usuario o contraseña incorrectos");
}
```

Comparto información en español sobre [operadores en Java](https://www.arkaitzgarro.com/java/capitulo-4.html)

Answer (score 5):

Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow.

Aparte del error de sintaxis que ya ha sido señalado, me permito recomendar para casos como estos el uso de *Operadores ternarios*. Estamos hablando de que vas a escribir 1 línea de código en vez de 5.

Aquí el *Operador ternario* hace la evaluación e imprime la cadena de la izquierda si es verdadero o la cadena de la derecha si es falso.

```
System.out.println( (contrasenaI >= 17) ? "enhorabuena, ha conseguido entrar a MexCex." : "[Error] nombre de usuario o contraseña incorrectos");
```

¿Qué más?  Nada más, ahí lo tienes, 1 línea en lugar de 5 líneas.

El operador ternario es muy simple, vamos a verlo con una asignación para entenderlo mejor.

```
Strint txt= (contrasenaI >= 17) ? "Es mayor" : "Es menor";
```

1. La evaluación es la parte izquierda del operador `(contrasenaI >= 17)` significa: *Si `contrasenaI` es mayor o igual a `17`*
2. `?`  es el operador ternario
3. `:` sirve como delimitador entre los posibles valores. A su izquierda está el valor que se asignará cuando la condición sea verdadera y a su derecha el valor que se asignará cuando la condición sea falsa.

Hay también operadores anidados que pueden ser útiles para evitar if y más if y más ifssss. Son muy útiles para asignaciones, o sea, para bloques en los que sólo necesites mostrar un mensaje y no hacer más operaciones dentro de ellos, como es el caso de tu ejemplo.

Si quieres profundizar sobre los ternarios, puedes consultar [este enlace](https://www.baeldung.com/java-ternary-operator).

Comment: Facilitan un montón el código, en mi primer año de carrera estaba muy perdida con el operador ternario, por más que lo miraba no entendía... ahora que lo manejo trato de usarlo siempre que se puede, excelente aporte y bien explicado :)

Comment: @Riaven son tan simples que funcionan igual en casi todos los lenguajes, de modo que cuando aprendes a usarlos en PHP o en otro, los puedes usar en los demás lenguajes del mismo modo. La claridad y limpieza que aportan al código es una maravilla.

Comment: A pesar que el operador ternario hace que el código se vea más elegante, es subjetivo. Conozco compañeros de mi facultad que no le gustan este operador, debido a que hace que el código se vea más ofuscado y peor cuando usas el operador ternario con múltiples condiciones.

Comment: @MrDave1999 me pasa exactamente lo mismo, soy estudiante y en el grupo con el que lo trabajo no lo entienden y de lleno hacen un simple  `if` , soy la única que lo usa, por lo que dices, que el código de cierta manera se vea mas elegante.